# Show that a function in three variables is non-negative on a specified range

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, roots

I want to show that a function $f$ in three variables $(x,y,z)$ is non-negative on a specified subdomain:
$0<=x,y,z<=1$.

The function comprises the following terms:
$1,x,x^2,y,y^2,z,z^m,z^{m+1}$ where $m$ is a positive integer. In $f$, the terms appear in all combinations e.g. $1x^2$ or $x^2y^2z^{m+1}$.

My strategy to show this is as follows:

1. Compute roots of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ --> $x_1, x_2$, i.e., two functions of $y,z$.
2. Investigate limit of $f$ if $x$ goes to $-\inf$

My results are as follows. Solving for the roots of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ (using the formula for polynomials of degree 2) yields two functions of $x,y$ that describe the "x-position" of the roots.

In my particular case, these roots turn out to lie in the following ranges: $x_1\in(-\inf,0]$ and $x_2\in[1, \inf)$.

The limit of $f$ if $x\rightarrow -\inf$ is found to be $-\inf$.

Can I conclude from these findings that $f$ is non-negative on the specified domain?